# GroundOverlay is not displaying but marker is displaying in Android GoogleMap v2

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay, google-maps-android-api-2

I am moving from Android googlemap `v1` to `v2`. I found that to display my own icons I have to use `GroundOverlay`(In `v1` I used `Overlay` ) Is there any other good solution?

1. Can I update the `GroundOverlay` location whenever I receive the location updates? (move the object) Google says "A ground overlay is an image that is fixed to a map"
2. Even if I add `GroundOverlay` I don't see it in my map. It just locate to Africa. No Icon. When I add `Marker` I can see that. But not `GroundOverlay`.

   ```
    BitmapDescriptor image = 
    BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE);
    LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds (new LatLng(00.00, 00.00), new LatLng(00.00, 00.00)); // get a bounds

    GroundOverlayOptions goo = new GroundOverlayOptions();
    goo.image(image);
    goo.positionFromBounds(bounds);
    goo.transparency(0);
    goo.visible(true);
    // Adds a ground overlay with 50% transparency.

    GroundOverlay groundOverlay = googleMap.addGroundOverlay(goo);
   ```

I have a demo in 2 days I really want this to work. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. The problem is with the zoom. The GroundOverlay is very small to see.

```
final LatLng cordination = new LatLng(40.714086, -74.228697);

goo.position(cordination, 500000f);
```

Now my problem is when I zoom the map. The GroundOverlay also zooming. I want this not to zoom and work like a Marker. Any one know how to do Pls respond.

Comment: I actually want to use my own overlay like in GoogleMap v1. But Since It is not possible with Googlemap V2 I use Marker.

Answer (score 0):

The ground overlay is something that behaves as if it is laying on the ground. So it will be turned, zoomed etc. together with the map.
So why do you prefer ground overlay over markers if you want to work it like a marker? You can use your own image also for a marker:

```
    BitmapDescriptor image = ....;
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
    options.position(coordinate);
    options.icon(image);
    googleMap.addMarker(options);
```

Comment: Initially I wanted to use my own overlay like in V1. But apparently its not possible. When I google some places I saw suggested to use GroundOverlay. But since I can't use it I use Marker now. Do you know how to get the marker list that available on the map already?

Comment: I am not sure, I got your question right. But the map displays only markers you have added on your own. So you can also maintain the list of markers on your own. The class GoogleMap does not have a method like getMarkerList.

Comment: Yes. You got me. I wanted to know is there a inbuilt list maintain by google api for marker list which we can get all the markers available.But now I have to maintain my own list.